# Why does OneToOne relationship cause long load - very slow Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-class-based-views

I've added a `OneToOneField` to my `models.py`. Once I do this my detail view takes almost a minute to load when before it took less than a second.

See below list for reference [method flowchart](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/) of what Django docs says happens in a DetailView.

Whatever is happening its happening after `render_to_response` (last one) and `get_success_url` (not listed). I added a `print('HELLO')` to both. I see render_to_response's HELLO immediately. Chrome spins/loads for a minute or two. And then I see `get_success_url`'s HELLO. What happens between `render_to_response` and `get_success_url`?

> Method Flowchart
>
> setup()
>
> dispatch()
>
> http_method_not_allowed()
>
> get_template_names()
>
> get_slug_field()
>
> get_queryset()
>
> get_object()
>
> get_context_object_name()
>
> get_context_data()
>
> get()
>
> render_to_response()

Comment: Likely that has something to do with the `__str__` of the model your `OneToOneField` refers to.

Comment: Can you share the 2 models and the part of the template where you render the field?